# Why is this code not iterating through all dict's elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict with many values, some of which are sub-dicts which also have sub-dicts and so on.

For every value, I need to build a string concatenating the top level key with a dot. So for example, if my dict is `{'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': {'f': 4}}}`, I need to build the following strings:

```
a
b.c
b.d
b.e.f
```

To do so, I wrote the following code

```
from types import GeneratorType


def get_parameter(d, top_level_param):
    for k, v in d.items():
        parameter = top_level_param + '.' + k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            get_parameter(v, parameter)
        else:
            yield parameter


d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': {'f': 4}}}

for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        parameter = get_parameter(v, k)
    else:
        parameter = k

    if isinstance(parameter, GeneratorType):
        for p in parameter:
            print(p)
    else:
        print(parameter)
```

However, the output is missing `b.e.f` and I don't know why. On paper, it looks like it should have been returned by `get_parameter()`.

Comment: Inside `get_parameter`, you call `get_parameter(v, parameter)`, when you probably want to use `yield from get_parameter(v, parameter)` instead.

Comment: @L3viathan ohh you are a life saver. That did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_parameter` recursively calls itself, but doesn't do anything with the results. Instead, you want to yield those results, too, which you can do with the `yield from` statement:

```
def get_parameter(d, top_level_param):
    for k, v in d.items():
        parameter = top_level_param + '.' + k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from get_parameter(v, parameter)
        else:
            yield parameter
```